# So many criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer

I'm working on an internet website that provides some services to internet users. So we have a administration system, where my cooperators from the business team can get the information they want, e.g. how many new users registered in the last 3 days? or how many articles posted with the tag "joke" etc. Thus in the administration system, there are a few pages for searching some tables with conditions. These pages are quite alike:

---

UserID:[--------------]    Nick Keyword:[------------]      Registered Time:[BEGIN]~[END]           [Search]

---

The searching results are listed here

---

The class `User` has more properties than just UserID/Nick/RegisterTime (as well as the user table), but only the 3 properties are treated as conditions. So I have a `UserSearchCriteria` class like:

```
public class UserSearchCriteria
{
    public long UserID { get; set; }
    public string NickKeyword { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisteredTimeStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisteredTimeEnd { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the data access layer, the search method takes an argument with its type `UserSearchCriteria`, and build the corresponding `Expression<Func<User, bool>>` to query. While out of theDAL, other developers can only search the user table with the 3 conditions provided by the criteria, for example, they can't search those users whose `City` property is "New York"(this is usually because this property has no index in DB, searching with it is slow).

**Question 1:** This implementation of enclosing the search is correct or not? Any suggestions?

**Question 2:** Now I find more criteria classes in the project like `ArticleSearchCriteria`,`FavouriteSearchCriteria` and etc, and the criteria will become more and more in the future I think. They have almost the same working mechanism but I need to repeat the code. Is there a better solution?

**P.S.** If you need these info:  jQuery + ASP.NET MVC 3 + MongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes perfect sense to me. If the user can't search by "anything" then using a search-by-template sort of approach doesn't make any sense. Also, if you try to make this more generic, it will get downright confusing. E.g., I would hate to code to something like:

```
class SearchCriteria{
   Dictionary<object,object> KeyValuePairs;
   EntityKind Entity;
}
```

to be used like this:

```
SearchCriteria sc = new SearchCriteria();
sc.KeyValuePairs.Add("UserId",32);
sc.Entity = EntityKind.User;
```

Eww. No compile time type checking, no checking to see if the entity and property match up, etc.

So, my answer is, yes :), I would use the design pattern you are currently using. Makes sense to me, and seems straightforward for anyone to see what you're doing and get up to speed.